# How to get WPF XAML Designer to play nicely with IValidatableObject from NET Standard 2.0 libraries?

Tags: wpf, nuget, system.componentmodel, .net-standard-2.0

### Background:

using Visual Studio 2017 v15.4 (no ReSharper or any weird extensions)

Repro solution includes 2 projects:

1. WPF project: .NET 4.6.1, using NuGet PackageReference format
2. Class library: NET Standard 2.0

Both projects have the `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` NuGet package installed.

### Problem

After upgrading my WPF project's NuGet format from the old *packages.config* to the new *PackageReference*, I started experiencing design-time errors:
[image]

Or sometimes the harsher flavor:
[image]

To start with, the following ViewModel code works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ValClass MyProp => new ValClass();
}

public class ValClass : IValidatableObject
{
    //Implementation stuff
}
```

However, if I then define an identical class in my NET Standard project, and include that as a type in my ViewModel, it produces the error.

Comparing an F12 on the IValidatableObject of these 2 classes:

The WPF version:

```
#region Assembly System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.1\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
#endregion
```

The NET Standard 2.0 version:

```
#region Assembly System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// C:\Users\a0110\.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.4.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
#endregion
```

It's clear that the same type and namespace are defined in assemblies with different names--not just assembly versions.

How can I get the XAML Designer to successfully locate whatever assembly is required to use `IValidatableObject`?

### Things I have Tried

- Installing VS v15.5 preview and targeting the WPF project to .NET 4.7 (also 15.5 preview 2 and 3, .NET 4.7.1)
- Adding the old `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` reference to the WPF project (with and without the NuGet version)
- reverting back to packages.config format (this didn't actually succeed; it appears that I'm stuck with PackageReference!)
- grabbing a copy of the System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll from the project's output folder and referencing it directly (VS would not let me do this)
- adding a `bindingRedirect` to my App.config
- adding `<DependsOnNETStandard>True</DependsOnNETStandard>` to the .csproj
- adding `<DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard2.0</DependsOnNETStandard>` to .csproj
- adding `<_HasReferenceToSystemRuntime>true</_HasReferenceToSystemRuntime>` to .csproj
- adding the NETStandard.Library NuGet package to the WPF project

### Update

For anyone else who is plagued by this issue, I have found a workaround:

1. Locate the System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll on your hard drive that your NET Standard project uses for IValidatableObject. Copy it to a location within your project.
2. Uninstall the System.ComponentModel.Annotations NuGet package from your solution
3. Give your NET Standard project a direct reference to DLL you copied
4. Give your WPF project a reference to the standard assembly System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
5. Upgrade your WPF project to target .NET 4.7.1
6. Compile. Your WPF design-time should be free from this error.

.

Comment: I have got a similar problem already for some weeks that I have been unable to solve. in an WCF service using EF Core 2.0 I used a Netstandard 2.0 library targeting Net 4.6.1 instead of a normal class library (it saves a few hundred megabytes). The library compiles normally but whenever I use the WCF-service from an application it always complains with the errormessage:  Cannot find System.ComponentModel.Annotations version 4.2.0.0

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase the title of this question.

Comment: @JRB there seems to be a lot of workarounds mentioned at https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues , but they all pertain to runtime issues. My issue is strictly a design-time issue.

Comment: thank you for the link. I came across one remark by JBE2277 of the 21th august 2017. That gave my an idea. Manually copy the .Netstandard 2.0 version of System.ComponentModel.Annotations timestamped 19th of july 2017 10:01 into the Setup folder of the WCF service. This solves my  problem.